# Can one turn visual studio's 'smart' sql query assistant off?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

When creating this query in the SQL querybuilder window in visual studio (2008):

```
 UPDATE       outgoing_messages
 SET                readstatus = 5
 FROM            outgoing_messages INNER JOIN
                     connections ON outgoing_messages.connectionid = connections.connectionid
 WHERE        (outgoing_messages.msgreference = '103') AND (connections.providerid = 9)
```

Visual studio knows better and criples it by turning it into:

```
 UPDATE       outgoing_messages
 SET                readstatus = 5
 FROM            outgoing_messages AS outgoing_messages_1 INNER JOIN
                     connections ON outgoing_messages_1.connectionid = connections.connectionid CROSS JOIN
                     outgoing_messages
 WHERE        (outgoing_messages_1.msgreference = '103') AND (connections.providerid = 9)
```

Which instead of singling out that 1 record with the specific msgreference and connectionid, it updates tons of records.

Now the crazy part is: when using the visual query builder and I drag and drop the query, it results in the exact same query, but now visual studio doesn't mess with it and executes it and all is fine.

If I copy and paste it again into a new querywindow, all is crippled again.

Is there a workaround for this 'smart' query crippler? (Turn it off for instance?)

Thanks!

EDIT:
p.s. this has been posted as a bug on Microsoft. Please start voting for it ;^)

here is the [link to microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509606)

Comment: You've got enough rep you should know better than to use the 'mssql' tag.

Comment: sorry about that. I type faster than the suggestion box so I missed it. It's just that I always refer to it as mssql instead of sql-server

Comment: If you feel it's a bug, then you should report it on http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/, then post the URL to your Connect issue here, so it can be voted upon.

Comment: Will do!  good idea.   Whats strange though is that I'm hardly an SQL guru and my queries are typically really simple. This was one of the harder ones to get right, and that was mainly due to the bug of studio. However, with more complex queries I see people on stack using, this kind of thing should have been noticed ages ago I'd presume

Comment: here is one which sounds like my issue. Although these rewrites don't cripple the query, they just rewrite it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=480516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft said they'll add the option to turn smart sql re-ordering off in the upcoming VisualStudio (2010)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same problem if you alias the table in the UPDATE clause rather than using the explicit name, i.e. this instead:

```
UPDATE       om
SET                readstatus = 5
FROM            outgoing_messages om INNER JOIN
              connections c ON om.connectionid = c.connectionid
WHERE        (om.msgreference = '103') AND (c.providerid = 9)
```

Comment: it gives the error'Column or expression 'readstatus' cannot be updated.'. I also tried the same query but with'om.readstatus' and exact same result...  the next windows says: invalid object name: om

Comment: the query is again transformed to: UPDATE       om
SET                om.readstatus = 5
FROM            outgoing_messages AS om INNER JOIN
                         connections AS c ON om.connectionid = c.connectionid CROSS JOIN
                         om
WHERE        (om.msgreference = '103') AND (c.providerid = 9)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with "VS knows better".
Ended up adding button to my application to run the right query.